# Error handling per user

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am trying to list the membership list for each user in the Active Directory Domain. I created the following line:

```
foreach($_ in $(Get-ADUser -Filter *).Name){            
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ | select Name,Groupscope,Groupcategory| sort Name
}
```

The problem is that running this line of code causes the following error to come up when a user doesn't have any groupmembership.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TEST USER' 
under: 'DC=contoso,DC=com'.
```

Adding `-Erroraction Silentlycontinue` behind `Get-ADPrinicpalGroupMembership` does not mitigate the problem. I'd rather not mess around with `$ErrorAction`. However, changing `$ErrorAction` to `"silentlycontinue"` and changing it back after the line completes ***does*** work. Not a pretty solution though. Is there any way to prevent the error showing otherwise?

Output for noam's solution: (Only shows a full list of groups available, not the memberships of the users)

```
name                                       groupScope             groupCategory
----                                       ----------             -------------
Administrators                            DomainLocal                  Security
Distributed COM Users                     DomainLocal                  Security
Domain Admins                                  Global                  Security
Domain Users                                   Global                  Security
Enterprise Admins                           Universal                  Security
Group Policy Creator Ow...                     Global                  Security
HelpLibraryUpdaters                       DomainLocal                  Security
Schema Admins                               Universal                  Security
TESTGROUP1                                     Global                  Security
Domain Guests                                  Global                  Security
Guests                                    DomainLocal                  Security
Denied RODC Password Re...                DomainLocal                  Security
Domain Users                                   Global                  Security
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve the MemberOf property and only run Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership when that property is not null.

```
$all = Get-ADUser -filter * -property memberOf
foreach ($usr in $all) {
    if ($usr.MemberOf) {
      $groups = $usr | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | select name, groupScope, groupCategory
      $usr.name + " belongs to the following groups:`n"
      $groups | sort name | ft -auto
    } else {$usr.name + " does not belong to any groups.`n"}
} #close foreach
```

[Custom objects](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/19/create-custom-objects-in-your-powershell-script.aspx) can also be useful for this kind of reporting.

[Get-Member](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176854.aspx) is useful for exploring object properties.

```
Get-ADUser joeUser -Property * | gm | where {$_.memberType -eq "Property"}
```

Comment: Edited OP to show the output. Kind of the same result as with dugas' solution.

Comment: Edited answer to show user names, too. Seemed like the question was more about suppressing the error.

Comment: This works for my purposes. Thank you. Very clever use of the memberOf property. Is there any way I can list all properties for a value easily ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the behavior of these cmdlets, but the error you are seeing may be caused by using only the Name property value to identify the object and not it's DN or other unique identifier ([Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617259.aspx). Try piping the output of Get-ADUser to Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership to see if the issue still occurs (see example below). Also, you may want to pipe the contents of Get-ADUser to the next cmdlet so you don't have to store the information returned by Get-ADUser in memory before processing.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

If the issue still exists:

You could use a try/catch block:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | %{ `
 try
 {
  Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_
 }
 catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityResolutionException]
 {
  #Log
  Write-Host "not found"
 }
}
```

Comment: Piping the Get-ADUser into the next cmdlet only gave me a full list of the Groups available. It didn't list any group memberships per user. The second option didn't return any output at all. Very interesting use of a try and catch however.

Comment: Second solution didn't return output because I assigned it to a variable. I have edited it to remove the assignment. Are you sure piping didn't work? I tested it on my machine... Try with a single user...